# how to remove(not delete) dynamically generated table elements?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Hi I have looped and echoed out this result

```
echo '<tr><td id="'.$row['productID'].'"><img height="150px" width="130px" 
src="products/'.$row['image_url'].'"></td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$row['price'].'</td></tr>';
```

The above resulted in a table full of data, now How do i remove a specific row, I want to remove it not delete from the table, as in a shopping cart where you remove the item but not delete it from the table. How would you use javascript or any other in this case?

Thank you very much.

Comment: remove where? javascript? php? in sql?

Answer (score 1):

Make a extra field in table.

Default value for the active Row is 1....

deactive row is value is 0

When retrieve the data form table used the where function for the Active rows

Answer (score 0):

Give it a `id` and using jQuery do as

```
$('yourid').hide(); // to hide

$('yourid').show(); // to show
```

Comment: @Bart Friederichs Not? i was always thinking jQuery was build with javascript

Comment: @RaymondNijland jQuery is written in Javascript. jQuery is certainly not standard or always available.

Comment: @Bart Friederichs i know it was twents (dutch) sarcasm

Answer (score 0):

Please you don't need JQuery for something simple like this..

```
document.getElementById('id_off_product').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this, although you can use it if you want.

**If you want to hide the product:**

```
document.getElementById('product_id').style.display = 'none';
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#product_id').hide();
```

**If you want to show it again:**

```
document.getElementById('product_id').style.display = '';
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#product_id').show();
```

**If you want to completely remove the product:**

```
document.getElementById('product_id').remove();
```

With jQuery:

```
$('#product_id').remove();
```

Also, you should probably put the `id` on the actual table row (`tr`) instead of on the table cell (`td`).

Comment: if you want to show it again it should be document.getElementById('product_id').style.display = 'block';

Comment: That will set the product's `display` to `block`, which won't necessarily be what you want. For example, the `display` of a `td` element should be `table-cell`. Just reseting the `display` property is the best solution.

Comment: maybe still wondering if it will trigger hasLayout property in IE based CSS rendering engine if you pass it in an empty string, i think it will not happen

Answer (score 0):

skimberk1's answer is most comprehensive. Here is an example that would allow a button on the row that would remove the row (parent/tr).

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>one</td><td>two</td><td id="test" onclick="removerow(this);">remove</td>
    </tr>
</table>

function removerow(e) {
    e.parentNode.remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FqbHW/19/embedded/result/

If completely removing is not desirable, then hiding or otherwise indicating it's inactive is possible... I would in that case also point you to Taveer's answer. You would need to track which rows are active/inactive. If you need additional details on this please comment.

Comment: Generally bad idea to use `e` or `event` as that's often used by browsers for event signals

Answer (score -1):

if u use jquery, u have to know the id of product to remove

```
$('td#productId').parent().hide();
```